# bind variables from store to component in angular ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data, angular13

I'm trying to bind the location variable in the component to another variable in the store via selector with ngrx v13 in angular, but when I put the variable with the property in the HTML I get an error:

error message: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Observable'

that is my code:

**app.selector.ts**

```
import { createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";

export const CurrentLocationSelector=(state:AppState) => state.currentLocation;
export const getCurrentLocation = createSelector(
    CurrentLocationSelector,
    (currentLocation: any) => {
      return [...new Set(currentLocation)];
    }
);
```

**that is my AppState:**

```
interface AppState{
    darktheme:boolean;
    temperatureUnit:string;
    currentLocation:any; // object with the current location
    locationAutoComplete:any[]; // array that contains the result from the autocomplete
    locationCurrentWeather:CurrentItem | null;
    Forecast5Days:ForecastItem[];
    Favorites:FavoriteItem[];
    loading:boolean;
    getData:boolean;
}
```

in my component i wrote:
**current-weather.component.html**

```
         <div class="left">
             <span class="locationName">{{location$.name}}</span>
             <span class="date">{{currentFullDate}}</span>
             <div class="weatherDescription">
                 <img [src]="imageCurrentWeather" class="weatherIcon">
                 <div class="weatherText">{{CurrentWeather.WeatherText}}</div>
             </div>
             <h1 [innerHTML]="CurrentWeather.Temperature + ' ' + currentUnit"></h1>
         </div>
```

in my **current-weather.component.ts** I wrote

```
  location$ = this.store.pipe(select(CurrentLocationSelector))
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that you are assigning your variable `location$` as an [observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable). This means that it is not a singular object representing your data but rather a collection of multiple values that could represent your data at any point in time. Think of it as a stream of data.

This means you need to get the value of your object a given point - usually the current point in time. To do this call `.subscribe()` on it to listen to the incoming observables and `.select` to listen to the your specific selector that contains the data you want via the following:

In your `current-weather.component.ts` file:

```
let $location;
this.store.select(CurrentLocationSelector).subscribe(location => {
  $location = location; // put a debug break point here to see your value get updated
});
```

Comment: I have try this but if i do subscribe i get an empty array without values even if i updating the location in the store.

Comment: How are you updating your store? If it is correctly updated, you should be able to use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) to see the value in your store at any given point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async pipe because location$ is observable.

```
<span class="locationName">{{(location$ | async).name}}</span>
```

current-weather.component.html

```
     <div class="left">
         <span class="locationName">{{(location$ | async).name}}/span>
         <span class="date">{{currentFullDate}}</span>
         <div class="weatherDescription">
             <img [src]="imageCurrentWeather" class="weatherIcon">
             <div class="weatherText">{{CurrentWeather.WeatherText}}</div>
         </div>
         <h1 [innerHTML]="CurrentWeather.Temperature + ' ' + currentUnit"></h1>
     </div>
```

[Reference for async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 0):

You actually flipped the .pipe and select over :

Try this:

```
this.location$ = this.store.select(CurrentLocationSelector).pipe(map((location)=> {return location;}))
```

If the problem persists, then it's most probably because of the selector, I recommend using createFeatureSelector:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
export const APP_STATE_NAME = 'app';

const getAppState =
  createFeatureSelector<AppState>(APP_STATE_NAME);

export const getLocation = createSelector(getAppState, (state) => {
  return state.currentLocation;
});
```